# getErrors and getInput

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wanting to add on the getErrors and getInput only in the event that the form failed to validate. I'm trying to figure out how I can add that onto the redirect variable.

```
/**
 * Store a newly created user in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $message = 'The form failed to validate.';
    $redirect = Redirect::to('users/create');

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        $message = 'The form failed to validate';

        // add on ->getErrors()->getInput();
    }

    User::create([
        'username' => $input['username'],
        'email_address' => $input['email_address'],
        'password' => $input['password'],
        'role_id' => $input['role']

    ]);

    return $redirect->with('message', $message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($validation->fails())
{
    $message = 'The form failed to validate';

    $redirect->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
}
```